# Get list of all primary keys of table in one row per table

Tags: oracle11g, primary-key

I have a list of 110 tables in a schema and want to get list of all primary keys. The tables will have multiple primary keys.
I want result to be one row per table so output should be 110 rows.

The query I'm using to get primary key is

```
`SELECT cols.table_name,  cols.column_name
 FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
 WHERE cols.table_name in ('C_ACTIVITY','C_HLD')
 AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
 AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
 AND cons.owner = cols.owner`
```

The output of above query is

```
`C_ACTIVITY PK1
 C_ACTIVITY PK2
 C_HLD P1
 C_HLD P2
 C_HLD P3`
```

But I want output to be

```
`C_ACTIVITY PK1,PK2
 C_HLD P1,P2,P3`
```

I tried using Pivot but was unable to get desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by table name and use LISTAGG to build the string:

```
 SELECT 
  cols.table_name, 
  LISTAGG(cols.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (order by cols.position) as columns
 FROM all_constraints cons
 JOIN all_cons_columns cols 
   ON cons.owner = cols.owner AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
 WHERE cols.table_name in ('C_ACTIVITY','C_HLD')
 AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
 GROUP BY cols.table_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the missing ORDER BY. I just notice that we look for the table names in cols.table_name. Thinking about it, I would change this to cons.table_name. The table names will be equal for a primary key constraint, so you can use either table. But I think it is much more straight-forward (and maybe faster) to say "give me all primary key constraints for tables x and y and then get the associated columns" than saying "look for primary key constraints in cons and for certain tables in cols and keep the matches".